# How to cast map<string,string> to map<string,timestamp> PySpark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column named **matchtimes** and I want to cast it to map<string,timestamp>

I have tried below method but gives the error as: NameError: name 'timestamp' is not defined

```
## Convert a StructType to MapType column :
## Useful when you want to move all Dynamic Fields of a Schema within a StructType column into a single MapType Column.

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import json

def toMap(d):
    if d:
        return(json.loads(d))  
    else:
        return None
    
# UDF returns a Map of Strings as Key:Value pair
map_udf=udf(lambda d: toMap(d),\
            MapType(StringType(),timestamp()))

df = df.withColumn("structtype_json_col", to_json('matchtimes'))
df = df.withColumn("matchtimes", map_udf(df.structtype_json_col)).drop("structtype_json_col")
df.printSchema()
```

[image]

Comment: do you mean`TimestampType()`?

Comment: @samkart yes, shall i check it with TimestampType() ?

Comment: yes, `TimestampType()` is a pyspark sql type, not `timestamp()`

Answer (score 1):

Spark has a function [`transform_values`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform_values) which is what should help you here (it's available starting from Spark 3.0).

only from Spark 3.1 there is a [pyspark `transform_values` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform_values.html#pyspark.sql.functions.transform_values) available.

Have a look at this SQL example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.sql(
    """
    WITH input(matchtimes) as
    
    (SELECT map('match1', '2022-07-14T09:39:44.612527', 'match2', '2022-07-14T09:39:44.612527')) 
    SELECT 
        matchtimes,
        typeof(matchtimes) as type_of_matchtimes,
        transform_values(matchtimes, (k, v) -> timestamp(v) ) as transformed, 
        typeof(transform_values(matchtimes, (k, v) -> timestamp(v) )) as type_of_transformed
    FROM input
    """
)

df.show()

+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|          matchtimes|type_of_matchtimes|         transformed| type_of_transformed|
+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[match1 -> 2022-0...|map<string,string>|[match1 -> 2022-0...|map<string,timest...|
+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

in pyspark 3.0 you can do:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = df.withColumn(
    "matchtimes_transformed", 
    expr("transform_values(matchtimes, (k, v) -> timestamp(v))")
```

in pyspark 3.1+:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import transform_values, to_timestamp

df = df.withColumn(
    "matchtimes_transformed", 
    transform_values(col("matchtimes"), lambda k, v: to_timestamp(v))
```